# strange out-of-memory exception during serialization

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, visual-studio-2008, datatable

I am using VSTS2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 to run this console application on x64 Server 2003 Enterprise with 12G physical memory.

Here is my code, and I find when executing statement bformatter.Serialize(stream, table), there is out of memory exception. I monitored memory usage through Perormance Tab of Task Manager and I find only 2G physical memory is used when exception is thrown, so should be not out of memory. :-(

Any ideas what is wrong? Any limitation of .Net serialization?

```
    static DataTable MakeParentTable()
    {
        // Create a new DataTable.
        System.Data.DataTable table = new DataTable("ParentTable");
        // Declare variables for DataColumn and DataRow objects.
        DataColumn column;
        DataRow row;

        // Create new DataColumn, set DataType, 
        // ColumnName and add to DataTable.    
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
        column.ColumnName = "id";
        column.ReadOnly = true;
        column.Unique = true;
        // Add the Column to the DataColumnCollection.
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create second column.
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        column.ColumnName = "ParentItem";
        column.AutoIncrement = false;
        column.Caption = "ParentItem";
        column.ReadOnly = false;
        column.Unique = false;
        // Add the column to the table.
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Make the ID column the primary key column.
        DataColumn[] PrimaryKeyColumns = new DataColumn[1];
        PrimaryKeyColumns[0] = table.Columns["id"];
        table.PrimaryKey = PrimaryKeyColumns;

        // Create three new DataRow objects and add 
        // them to the DataTable
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5000000; i++)
        {
            row = table.NewRow();
            row["id"] = i;
            row["ParentItem"] = "ParentItem " + i;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return table;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable table = MakeParentTable();
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        bformatter.Serialize(stream, table);   // out of memory exception here
        Console.WriteLine(table.Rows.Count);

        return;
    }
```

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: Thanks Marc, your reply is so great and I have marked it as answered. Appreciate if you could share your expertise about virtual memory here,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297797/windows-32-bit-virtual-memory-page-mapping-issue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note: `DataTable` defaults to the xml serialization format that was used in 1.*, which is incredibly inefficient. One thing to try is *switching to the newer format*:

```
 dt.RemotingFormat = System.Data.SerializationFormat.Binary;
```

---

Re the out-of-memory / 2GB; individual .NET objects (such as the `byte[]` behind a `MemoryStream`) are limited to 2GB. Perhaps try writing to a `FileStream` instead?

(edit: nope: tried that, still errors)

I also wonder if you may get better results (in this case) using `table.WriteXml(stream)`, perhaps with compression such as GZIP if space is a premium.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for your valuable reply. For byte[] limitation of 2G size, could you recommend me some more documents about this topic please? I never know this and want to learn more backgrounds.

Comment: "edit: nope: tried that, still errors" -- what do you mean tried that, still errors? You mean which method still has errors?

Comment: Marc, I have tried to use writexml and it works. But the result file size is only 520M. It is far less than 2G. How do you prove my original code hits the 2G limitation?

Comment: Re last... I don't; I merely point out that even with a stonking amount of memory, some things remain capped in size. Arrays (which underpin other things like lists and MemoryStream) and strings being the most obvious. If you are hitting some *other* limitation of `BinaryFormatter`, then to be honest you're scuppered no matter whether it is system memory, list size, or simply karma. So if WriteXml works, stick with that ;-p

Comment: Re still errors: I mean that switching to a FileStream and using your code "as is" still has the problem; so it isn't necessarily *purely* limited to MemoryStream limitations; but note that since BinaryFormatter performs object tracking internally there are a lot of other things going on anyway.

Comment: Re 2GB; this might be in the CLI spec (ECMA335) - I can't be sure; but it is discussed more here: http://blogs.msdn.com/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx

Comment: As for the filesize compared to memory. Part of the answer is that strings in memory in .Net are UTF-16, but UTF-8 when writing them (most likely). This means in your test that you will half the bytes for the string when writing them.

Comment: Thanks Marc and Mikael, your reply is so great! I have a related question here, appreciate if you could help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297797/windows-32-bit-virtual-memory-page-mapping-issue

Comment: I was trying to binary serialize 100K rows and was getting out of memory exceptions... Changed this property as recommended and now 100K rows serialized and gzipped is 7.9mb... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

As already discussed this is a fundamental issue with trying to get contiguous blocks of memory in the Gigabyte sort of size.

You will be limited by (in increasing difficulty)

1. The amount of addressable memory

   - since you are 64bit this will be you 12GB physical memory, less any holes in it required by devices plus any swap file space.
   - Note that you must be running an app with the [relevant PE headers that indicate it can run 64bit](http://blogs.msdn.com/joshwil/archive/2005/05/06/415191.aspx) or you will run under WoW64 and only have 4GB of address space.
   - Also note that the default target was [changed in 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/rmbyers/archive/2009/06/08/anycpu-exes-are-usually-more-trouble-then-they-re-worth.aspx), a [contentious change](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=455103&wa=wsignin1.0).
2. The [CLR's limitation that no single object may consume more than 2GB of space](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241064%28VS.80%29.aspx).
3. Finding a contiguous block within the available memory.

You can find that you run out of space before the CLR limit of `2` because the backing buffer in the stream is expanded in a 'doubling' fashion and this swiftly results in the buffer being allocated in the Large Object Heap. This heap is not compacted in the same way the other heaps are(1) and as a result the process of building up to the theoretical maximum size of the buffer under `2` fragments the LOH so that you fail to find a sufficiently large contiguous block before this happens.

Thus a mitigation approach if you are *close* to the limit is to set the initial capacity of the stream such that it definitely has sufficient space from the start via [one of the constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx3c0489.aspx).

Given that you are writing to the memory stream as part of a serialization process it would make sense to actually use streams as intended and use only the data required.

- If you are serializing to some file based location then stream it into that directly.
- If this is data going into a Sql Server database consider using:

  - [FILESTREAM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716724.aspx) 2008 only I'm afraid.
  - From 2005 onwards you can [read/write in chunks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1904w6t%28VS.80%29.aspx) but writing is [not well integrated into ADO.Net](http://www.codeassassin.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,41e69e3d-2531-411a-b32d-e6e19b8a1dd9.aspx)
  - For versions prior to 2005 there are relatively unpleasant [workarounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3517w44b.aspx)
- If you are serializing this in memory for use in say a comparison then consider streaming the data being compared as well and diffing as you go along.
- If you are persisting an object in memory to recreate it latter then this really should be going to a file or a memory mapped file. In both cases the operating system is then free to structure it as best it can (in disk caches or pages being mapped in and out of main memory) and it is likely it will do a better job of this than most people are able to do themselves.
- If you are doing this so that the data can be compressed then consider using streaming compression. Any block based compression stream can be fairly easily converted into a streaming mode with the addition of padding. If your compression API doesn't support this natively consider using one that does or writing the wrapper to do it.
- If you are doing this to write to a byte buffer which is then pinned and passed to an unmanaged function then use the [UnmanagedMemoryStream](http://www.codeassassin.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,41e69e3d-2531-411a-b32d-e6e19b8a1dd9.aspx) instead, this stands a slightly better chance of being able to allocate a buffer of this sort of size but is still not guaranteed to do so.

Perhaps if you tell us *what* you are serializing an object of this size for we might be able to tell you better ways to do it.

---

1. This is an implementation detail you should not rely on

Comment: Thanks ShuggyCoUk, your reply is so great! I have a related question here, appreciate if you could help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297797/windows-32-bit-virtual-memory-page-mapping-issue

Answer (score 1):

1) The OS is x64, but is the app x64 (or anycpu)? If not, it is capped at 2Gb.

2) Does this happen 'early on', or after the app has been running for some time (i.e. n serializations later)? Could it maybe be a result of large object heap fragmentation...?

Comment: Thanks KristoferA, for your concerns, 1. I build into Any CPU, so it should be able to consume more than 2G physical memory, correct? 2. The out of memory exception occurs after 1 minutes, after method MakeParentTable returns successful. So I think it should not be a result of large object heap fragmentation? Any comments?

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, it actually goes up to 3.7GB before giving a memory error here (Windows 7 x64).
Apparently, it would need about double that amount to complete.

Given that the application uses 1.65GB after creating the table, it seems likely that it's hitting the 2GB `byte[]` (or any single object) limit Marc Gravell is speaking of (1.65GB + 2GB ~= 3.7GB)

Based on this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx), I suppose you could allocate your memory using the WINAPI, and write your own MemoryStream implementation using that. That is, if you really wanted to do this. Or write one using more than one array of course :)

Comment: Hi Thorarin, 1. for the 2G size limitation of byte[], I want to learn more. Do you have any more related documents? 2. The number 1.65GB and 2GB means whose footprint in your calculation?

Comment: 1.65GB for the DataTable itself. All I could find on the 2GB limit (other than that it exists) is http://blogs.msdn.com/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx

Comment: Thanks Thorarin, 1. I understand 2GB limitation. But how do you prove the 2GB is actually reached? :-) 2. For the 1.65G how do you calculate such precise number? :-)

Comment: Thanks Thorarin, your reply is so great! I have a related question here, appreciate if you could help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297797/windows-32-bit-virtual-memory-page-mapping-issue