# Serialization OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, out-of-memory

I have a program that builds a large xml based structure into classes and holds them in a collection to be serialized... call them contracts. Each contract goes into the collection and consist of objects which will represent the nodes in the XML doc. This all woks fine and dandy, but now we are hitting 10000 items in the collection. Task manager still puts us at 586 megs of usage on a 8 gb machine.

The problem comes in when I serialize down to a file:

```
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PolicyExtract));
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("ent", "http://xxxxxx.com/V2.0/enrollmententities");

        StreamWriter fs = new StreamWriter(filePath);
        serializer.Serialize(fs, this, ns);

        fs.Close();
```

This being the class or collection itself. The file is huge (as expected) but not enough to take all the memory. I am receiving a `System.OutOfMemoryException` at this point and no file is generated at all.

So to recap, I'm trying to serialize a large collection (still well within memory limits) into a file and receiving an `OutOfMemoryException` and no file.

Any ideas?

Comment: A 32bit process, even on a 64bit machine will only be able to access a maximum of 3GB - make sure you are running the process as 64bit.

Comment: ... and only 2GB per object instance, even on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - by default, 2GB, with certain OS startup switch, 3GB. The actual address space is 4GB, but not all of it is available.

Comment: @Oded Ah, I missed to note the word maximum.. NVM

Comment: I can imagine the XmlSerializer has considerable internal overhead. If  you're reaching its limits either increase memory as fellow commentators noted; or write collection start/end tag manually and use  XmlSerializer just for serialization of items.

Comment: Similar discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291735/strange-out-of-memory-exception-during-serialization

Comment: but im still below 2 gb with the file and the process

Comment: What message (string) is associated with `OutOfMemoryException`?

Comment: 11/15/2013 5:06:44 PM: Error->Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
11/15/2013 5:06:45 PM: Stack Trace->    at System.Text.StringBuilder.ExpandByABlock(Int32 minBlockCharCount)
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(Char* value, Int32 valueCount)
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(Char[] value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 charCount)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
   at PolicyHubFeed.Program.Main(String[] args)

Answer (score 0):

We've had similar problems in the opposite direction when deserializing large XML files (> 1.4 GB). We also experienced OutOfMemoryExceptions well before a process limit was reached.
I also like XML serialization for its simplicity, but in case of large portions of data, it is required to have more control over the serialization process as XML handling usually is connected with lots of strings that are created in memory.
We were able to solve our problems with XmlReader and calls to [GC.Collect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-us/library/system.gc.collect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) after several thousands of iterations. In your case, using [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/system.xml.xmlwriter%28v=vs.89%29) to write the data and throwing in a GC.Collect after some iterations should also ease the problem. How often you need to call the garbage collector depends on your scenario and might involve some trial and error. Do not call it too often, as it is a heavyweight operation.
Also, you should inspect your data structures whether there are duplicate data that you might be able to substitute by methods.
Downside is of course that the serialization code becomes much longer and less easy to handle as you might need to reflect changes in the data structures also in the serialization code.

Answer (score -3):

Go to your project properties -> build tab -> Platform target: change "Any CPU" to "x64" (assuming your pc supports it)

Comment: You need 64-bit infrastructure for this. It would be useful to know which exception you receive...